# Chef fails my assets:precompile step on Opsworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chef-infra, sprockets, aws-opsworks

Deploying my app to Amazon's Opsworks, my asset pre-compilation step regularly fails.

The Chef recipe looks like this:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
    before_restart do
      rails_env = deploy[:rails_env]
      current_release = release_path
      execute "rake assets:precompile" do
        user deploy[:user]
        cwd current_release
        command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
        environment "RAILS_ENV" => rails_env
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...which generates this error:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''
---- Begin output of bundle exec rake assets:precompile ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: I, [2014-07-15T02:05:30.399857 #12281]  INFO -- : Writing <asset path>
...
...
...
---- End output of bundle exec rake assets:precompile ----
Ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned
```

The compilation step seems to be successful, so why is Chef erroring out?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, it looks like Sprockets is logging info messages to standard error, which Chef is interpreting as failure.

There's [a pull request to change this behaviour](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/552), but it seems to have stalled with one of the contributors...

So in the meantime, I'm redirecting stderr to stdin like this:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
    before_restart do
      rails_env = deploy[:rails_env]
      current_release = release_path
      execute "rake assets:precompile" do
        user deploy[:user]
        cwd current_release
        command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile 2>&1"
        environment "RAILS_ENV" => rails_env
      end
    end
  end
end
```